# Jenkins: Deploying & updating java (& others) on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, remote-access, remote-server

I'd like to use Jenkins to deploy/update programs on a remote windows server (not always the same version). By "programs", I mean java, tomcat, ActiveMQ and some server executables (.exe).

To update some of those, I would need to stop the associated service, deploy the updated executable & restart the service (like tomcat). Some others would just need to be installed on the remote machine without prompt (like updating java from version 8 to 9).

The problem is I'm not sure how to configure Jenkins to do these jobs on remote windows environnement, and I'm not sure what would be the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins [has the ability to run Powershell](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin) - which is one of the most straightforward ways to make changes in Windows.  You can use the [Start-Service or Stop-Service cmdlets](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/01/22/powershell-to-manage-system-services.aspx) for service management.

For script-based installation, my go-to is [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), which allows you to install almost anything.

For example, once installed, you can use this simple command to install Java:

```
choco install jdk8
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as @sharpslinger said Powershell is the right tool for the job. I would go for Powershell DSC. Useful DSC resources in your case:

For starting / stopping service use [Service resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/serviceresource):

```
Service ServicesStop
{
    Name = "TheTestService"
    State = "Stopped"
}
```

To deploy your executable you can use [File resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/fileresource):

```
File CopyMyExe 
{ 
    Ensure = "Present" 
    Type = "File" 
    SourcePath = "MySource.jar"
    DestinationPath = "MyDestination.jar"
}
```

To install java silently you can use [Script resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/scriptresource). Source of example below: [link](https://erictummers.com/2018/07/10/tfs-tips-1-install-java-runtime-on-local-server/).

```
# This allows the reboot
LocalConfigurationManager
{
    RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
}

Script Java
{
    GetScript  = { return @{} }
    TestScript = { return Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' }
    SetScript  = {   
        $installer = "jre-8u144-windows-x64.exe"
        Start-Process $installer -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait
        # signal reboot
        $global:DSCMachineStatus = 1
    }
}
```

Jenkins' job will be to simply call Powershell script that deploys your application.